# Internal Server error 500 when trying to execute GET from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internal-server-error, http-status-code-500

I've been working with my teamates on a web project for a while now,
the project uses serverside commands such as GET AND POST (from our collage Server) which are both works fine while starting the project with visual studio localy on our PC's.
Only after loading the project to our collage server, some of the Get requests wont work for some reason.
Faild to load reasource: the server responded with a status of 500 (internal server error).

attaching my code with the GET (ajaxcall) and printscreen of the error.

please help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>





       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link href='https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar@3.10.1/dist/fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar@3.10.1/dist/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
    enter code here
    <script src="../Scripts/ajaxCalls.js"></script>


    <link href="../Style/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Schieffer - Home</title>

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="../img/favicon s/apple-icon-57x57.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="../img/favicon s/apple-icon-60x60.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="../img/favicon s/apple-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="../img/favicon s/apple-icon-76x76.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="../img/favicon s/apple-icon-114x114.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="../img/favicon s/apple-icon-120x120.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="../img/favicon s/apple-icon-144x144.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="../img/favicon s/apple-icon-152x152.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="../img/favicon s/apple-icon-180x180.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="../img/favicon s/android-icon-192x192.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="../img/favicon s/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="../img/favicon s/favicon-96x96.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="../img/favicon s/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/ms-icon-144x144.png">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">





    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <link href='../packages/core/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='../packages/daygrid/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='../packages/timegrid/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='../packages/list/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src='../packages/core/main.js'></script>
    <script src='../packages/interaction/main.js'></script>
    <script src='../packages/daygrid/main.js'></script>
    <script src='../packages/timegrid/main.js'></script>
    <script src='../packages/list/main.js'></script>
    <script>


        var today = new Date();
        var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
        var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
        var products = new Array();



        var Orders = new Array();

        $(document).ready(function () {

            ajaxCall("GET", "../api/Order", "", succGet, errorGet)

        });

        Date.prototype.addHours = function(h) {
        this.setTime(this.getTime() + (h*60*60*1000));
        return this;
}

        function succGet(data) {

            alert("success");
            console.log(data);
            for (o in data) {
                var descriptions = 'פרטי הזמנה: \n שם מוצר: ' + data[o]["Description"] + ', \n' + 'מק"ט: ' + data[o]["Makat"] + ', \n' + 'שם לקוח: ' + data[o]["CustomerName"] + ', \n' + 'מספר לקוח: ' + data[o]["CustomerId"] + ', \n' + 'אורך: ' + data[o]["Length"] + ' מטר , \n' + 'תאריך אספקה: ' + data[o]["DueDate"] + '.';
                Orders.push({ title: data[o]["Description"], start: new Date(data[o]["ProdDate"]), end: new Date(data[o]["ProdDate"]).addHours(data[o]["ReqProcessTime"]), description: descriptions });
                //products.push(
                //    {
                //        title: ''+data[o]["Description"],
                //        start: '2020-04-0' + (o + 1),
                //        description: 'Info: מוצר: '+data[o]["Description"] +'מק"ט: ' + data[o]["Makat"] + ', אורך: ' + data[o]["Length"] +' ס"מ .',
                //    })
            }
            alert(Orders);

            //var notOrders = [
                //{
                    //title: Orders[0][0],
                    //start: '2020-04-04',
                    //description: 'ס.מסוע 750 מ"מ 4, מ"ס לקוח: 433, שם לקוח: אא מסועים, ת.אספקה 20.04.2020'
                //}, {
                    //title: 'ס.מסוע 350 מ"מ 6',
                    //start: '2020-04-04',
                    //description: 'ס.מסוע 750 מ"מ 4, מ"ס לקוח: 433, שם לקוח: אא מסועים, ת.אספקה 20.04.2020'

                //}, {
                    //title: 'ס.מסוע 900 מ"מ 3',
                    //start: '2020-04-04',
                    //description: 'ס.מסוע 950 מ"מ 4, מ"ס לקוח: 433, שם לקוח: אא מסועים, ת.אספקה 20.04.2020'

                //}, {
                    //title: 'ס.מסוע 200 מ"מ 4',
                    //start: '2020-04-06T11:00:00',
                    //description: 'ס.מסוע 200 מ"מ 4, מ"ס לקוח: 433, שם לקוח: אא מסועים, ת.אספקה 20.04.2020'

                //}, {
                    //title: 'ס.מסוע 650 מ"מ 6',
                    //start: '2020-04-06T15:00:00',
                    //description: 'ס.מסוע 750 מ"מ 4, מ"ס לקוח: 433, שם לקוח: אא מסועים, ת.אספקה 20.04.2020'

                //}, {
                    //title: 'ס.מסוע 750 מ"מ 4',
                    //start: '2020-04-07T14:00:00',
                    //description: 'ס.מסוע 750 מ"מ 4, מ"ס לקוח: 433, שם לקוח: אא מסועים, ת.אספקה 20.04.2020'
                //}, {
                    //title: 'ס.מסוע 400 מ"מ 1',
                    //start: '2020-04-09T09:00:00',
                    //description: 'ס.מסוע 400 מ"מ 1, מ"ס לקוח: 433, שם לקוח: אא מסועים, ת.אספקה 20.04.2020'
                //},
            //];
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list'],
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
                },




                defaultDate: today,



                navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views

                weekNumbers: true,
                weekNumbersWithinDays: true,
                weekNumberCalculation: 'ISO',

                editable: true,
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

                eventRender: function (info) {
                    $(info.el).tooltip({ title: info.event.extendedProps.description });
                },
                events: Orders
                //eventMouseEnter: function (arg) {
                //    //if (confirm('delete event?')) {
                //    //info.event.setProp('backgroundColor', '#00CCFF');

                //    alert(arg.event.title);
                //    //}

                //}
            });

            calendar.render();
        }

        function errorGet(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }







        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

        });</script>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <script>



    </script>




    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row d-none d-xl-block ">

            <ul>
                <li style="padding-top:33px; margin-left:-30px;"> <a href="SHome.html"><img style="width:300px; height:80px" src="../img/schieffer_logo trans.png" href="Home.html" /></a></li>
                <li class="navbtn"><a href="SOrders.html"> <img src="../img/btnnn - orders - trans.png" /></a></li>
                <li class="navbtn"><a href="SHome.html"> <img src="../img/btnnn - report - trans.png" /></a></li>
                <li class="navbtn"><a href="SOrderInvite.html"> <img src="../img/btnnn - invite - trans.png" /></a></li>
                <li class="navbtn"><a href="SAddWorker.html"><img src="../img/btnnn - addworker - trans.png" /></a></li>
                <li class="line-navbar"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>



        <div class="row d-xl-none navbar-collapse-res">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="SHome.html"><img class="navbar-collapse-res-logo" src="../img/schieffer_logo trans.png" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="active"><a class="navbar-collapse-item-res" href="SHome.html">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a class="navbar-collapse-item-res" href="SOrders.html">הזמנות</a></li>
                            <li><a class="navbar-collapse-item-res" href="SHome.html">דוחות</a></li>
                            <li><a class="navbar-collapse-item-res" href="SOrderInvite.html">הזמנת מוצר</a></li>
                            <li><a class="navbar-collapse-item-res" href="SAddWorker.html">הוספת עובד</a></li>
                            <li><a class="navbar-collapse-item-res" href="SLogin.html">התנתק</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>



            <div class="row">
                <div class="header-style-home-res">תכנית יצור נוכחית</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="gray-background-res">
                    <div id='calendar'></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>












</body>
</html>
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUlsR.png)
[image: error2]

Comment: A 500 error means something went wrong on the server, not your JS. You need to debug that instead.

Comment: Also note for future questions that you should only include the relevant code, not just dump the entire page, including the logic unnecessary to the problem at hand

Comment: Thanks I'm still new at this, so 500 error means that there is something wrong with the server I'm sending the GET request to? cause most of the GETs works fine @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: That's correct. Remember that the server error could well be being caused by the data you send in the request. In any case, you need to debug your server side code to determine what the problem is